# propertychange not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using `propertychange` for ie's to capture the input values. it's not working with ie11. any one suggest me the correct way to use it to work with all ie's.

here is my code and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>PropertyChange</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="propChange.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input').on('propertychange', function(){
        console.log(this.value);
    });
});
```

In the console I am getting this:

```
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
```

and

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
```

Comment: are there any console errors, please check and provide jsfiddle of this

Comment: use `$('input').on('change')`

Comment: Found this: "The onpropertychange event is only supported in conjunction with the legacy attachEvent IE-only event registration model, which has deprecated since Windows Internet Explorer 9 in favor of the W3C standard "addEventListener" event model." -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Heejin, OP is using 'propChange.js' and I think thats why binding propertychange event

Answer (score 0):

Use DOMSubTreeModified to make it work in IE11 (IE11 manipulates DOM) :

```
$('input').on('DOMSubTreeModified propertychange', function(){
        console.log(this.value);
    });
```